# How to resolve Error while updating property 'd' of a view managed by:RNSVGPath InvalidNumber

Tags: php, react-native, react-native-chart-kit

I need to load my SQL server data using react-native-chart-kit, but when I use this code I get this error :

Error while updating property 'd' of a view managed by: RNSVGPath
null
InvalidNumber

```js
import React from "react";
import { Text, View, Dimensions } from "react-native";
import { LineChart } from "react-native-chart-kit";
export default class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      data: {
        labels: [
          "Gen",
          "Feb",
          "Mar",
          "Apr",
          "Mag",
          "Giu",
          "Lug",
          "Ago",
          "Set",
          "Ott",
          "Nov",
          "Dic",
        ],
        datasets: [
          {
            data: [],
          },
        ],
      },
    };
  }

  GetData = () => {
    const self = this;

    return fetch("http://192.168.1.5:80/graph.php")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        // clone the data from the state
        const dataClone = { ...self.state.data };

        const values = responseJson.map((value) => value.ChiffreAffaire);

        dataClone.datasets[0].data = values;

        self.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          data: dataClone,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <LineChart
          data={this.state.data}
          width={Dimensions.get("window").width} // from react-native
          height={220}
          yAxisLabel={"$"}
          chartConfig={chartConfig}
          bezier
          style={{
            marginVertical: 8,
            borderRadius: 16,
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

The data I get from my php file is like :`[{"ChiffreAffaire":"4800.00"},{"ChiffreAffaire":"12000.00"}]`

```php
<?php

$serverName="DESKTOP-T5SLVUB\SQL2008R2";
$connectionInfo=array("Database"=>"Netos_DB","UID"=>"sa","PWD"=>"123");
$conn=sqlsrv_connect($serverName,$connectionInfo);
$sql = "select  ChiffreAffaire from V502_client where Mois=2 and Annee=2020 "; 
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql  );
 while( $row[] = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC) ){
      $Item = $row;
      $json = json_encode($Item);    
}

echo $json;
?>
```

I don't know what is the problem and why I m getting this error; please if you have any Idea

Comment: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg/issues/1084

Comment: It didn't resolve my problem ,I read that the cause of my problem is data I get from my API ,Any Idea???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
{
    this.state.loadComplete &&
        (<LineChart
            data={this.state.dt}
            width={Dimensions.get("window").width} // from react-native
            height={this.height}
            yAxisLabel=""
            yAxisSuffix="b"
            yAxisInterval={1} // optional, defaults to 1
            chartConfig={this.config}
            bezier
            style={{
                marginVertical: 8,
                borderRadius: 16
            }}
        />)
}
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it does it.

Comment: that code helps you to draw a chart (Linechart for this case) using dynamic data from yoour database or just data that u defined in table

Answer (score 3):

I resolved my problem !!!! 
for those having same problem ,I will explain the error to u :
Well the problem was that my LineChart take data before its reload completely so it gets null and this an Invalid format of number ;

So what you have to do ,is add in render method  before return :

```
 if(this.state.isLoading){
    return(
      <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 20}}>
          <ActivityIndicator/>
        </View>

    )
  }
```

So we are not going to pass to LineChart until allll data is loaded